# Delete column in dataframe without index heading

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and searched this forum without finding an answer to this question.  I have a dataframe and the first column has no heading but consists of descending numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... to the height of the matrix (its a column of row numbers).  I am trying to delete this column and used the following line of code:

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This line dropped my second column from the left rather than the first column which I wanted to drop.  How do I drop or delete this first column?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: That's the index. You can make one of your columns the index using `.set_index()`. Please see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing

Comment: Thank you for the help.  After reading the 57 page reference I attempted to reassign the index column to the second column to get rid of the first numbered column. I tried the following line of code: df.set_index('Name of second column', inplace=True).  However the output was: KeyError: 'Name of second column'.  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I was able to reassign the key to the second column which dropped the first numbered index column. However this also shifted the new key column down by 1 row.  I tried to move it 1 row back up with this line: df[' new index column']=df[new index column'].shift(-1), but received as output: KeyError: new index column'.  Do you know how to shift this new key column up a row and delete the bottom row so all the columns are of equal length?

Comment: That's simply how Pandas represents the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` does not allow a `DataFrame` or `Series` object to exist without an `Index`. The simplest index possible is a `RangeIndex`, which just counts up for 0, as in your case.

`pandas 2.0` [might make indices optional](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas2/issues/17). But, this is still in the distant future.